# SQL: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

Please help me how to fixed this issue

> *Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.*

Here is my query

```
SELECT  a.RegId,
        a.PropertyThumbnail
FROM    tblPropertyDetail a
WHERE   a.RegId NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT  RegId,
                    COUNT(RegId) AS NumOccurrences
            FROM tblPropertyDetail
            GROUP BY RegId
            HAVING (COUNT(RegId) > 1)
        )
```

Answer (score 6):

remove this column in the subquery `COUNT(RegId) AS NumOccurrences`

```
SELECT a.RegId,
        a.PropertyThumbnail
FROM tblPropertyDetail a
WHERE a.RegId NOT IN (
                SELECT RegId
                FROM tblPropertyDetail
                GROUP BY RegId
                HAVING (COUNT(RegId) > 1)
                )
```

when using `NOT IN`, it is expected that the number of columns return by the subquery is only one.

Alternatively, you can also do this using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.RegId,
        a.PropertyThumbnail
FROM    tblPropertyDetail a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT RegId, COUNT(RegId) AS NumOccurrences
            FROM tblPropertyDetail
            GROUP BY RegId
            HAVING (COUNT(RegId) > 1)
        ) b ON a.RegId = b.RegId
WHERE   b.RegId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer2005+ use CTE with aggregate window function

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT RegId, PropertyThumbnail, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY RegId) AS cnt
  FROM tblPropertyDetail
  )
  SELECT RegId, PropertyThumbnail
  FROM cte
  WHERE cnt <= 1
```

Comment: +1 CTE FTW, powerful feature that often makes the query easier to read.